# creating graphs in Java with ArrayLists

Tags: java, graph, arraylist

I'm new to Java and I wanted to practice by creating a graph. I am having trouble creating the graph because I'm not sure how to do so correctly. I am lacking the logic and being new in Java makes things quite difficult. I was wondering if anyone could help me or guide me in the right path! Thanks!

Basically I am trying to create something like this as a graph. A node will contain an `ArrayList` for it's neighbors.

```
    A,B,C,D
A = 0,1,3,0
B = 1,0,0,2
C = 1,0,0,3   //shorter path to A (cycle)
D = 0,0,3,0
```

The nodes are connected to each other with or without weights (if I change numbers to 1)

Here is what I have so far (it is incomplete):

```
public class GraphNode {
    boolean visited;


    public GraphNode() {
        List<GraphNode> node = new ArrayList<GraphNode>();  // store neighbors
        this.visited = false;

    }

    public void addNeighbor(GraphNode root, GraphNode target, int distance) {
        root.add(target);     // cannot use "add" to ArrayList

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put ArrayList inside your GraphNode class. Instead define a graph class that contains a 2D array of GraphNode (the graph's adjacency matrix). This decouples the node from the logic involved with managing a collection of nodes in a graph. This is what's done in the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) java graph library. In fact, I recommend trying this library. It supports running algorithms on the graph (ex Dijkstra's algorithm) and visualizing the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to access the `ArrayList` from accross methods within the *same* class, you would need to promote that local variable to a global variable (field), like below:

```
public class GraphNode {
    /*Global Variables*/
    boolean visited;
    List<GraphNode> nodeNeighbours;
    /*Global Variables*/

    public GraphNode() {
        this.nodeNeighbours = new ArrayList<GraphNode>();  // store neighbors
        this.visited = false;

    }

    public void addNeighbor(GraphNode target) {
        this.nodeNeighbours.add(target);    //This will add target to the neighbours of this given node.
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Shortest path algorithms (as far as memory serves) have a fixed starting point, meaning that the root will always be the same. The same can be said to their weight, which usually does not change.

However, as different paths are explored, the distance to the root node is most likely to change. With that in mind, you could re write your class as follows:

```
public class GraphNode {
    /*Global Variables*/
    protected double weight;
    protected double distanceFromRoot;
    protected List<GraphNode> neighbours;
    protected boolean visited;
    /*Global Variables*/

    public GraphNode(double weight, double distanceFromRoot) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.distanceFromRoot = distanceFromRoot;
        this.neighbours = new ArrayList<GraphNode>();
        this.visited = false;
    }

    public void setDistanceFromRoot(double distanceFromRoot) {
         this.distanceFromRoot = distanceFromRoot;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
         this.visited = visited;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public double getDistanceFromRoot() {
        return this.distanceFromRoot;
    }

    public List<GraphNode> getNeighbours() {
        return this.neighbours;
    }   

    public void addNeighbour(GraphNode neighbour) {
        this.neighbours.add(neighbour)
    }
}
```

This might be a little bit more extensive than what you started with. The main change in your code is that this code promoted *encapsulation*. Encapsulation is one of the core fundamentals of OOP in which you essentially deny direct access to your global variables. The access is offered through appropriate `set` and `get` method which you can use to define how and when does someone external to your program modifies the internal state of your program.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the formulation not completely accurate. Rather: "promote the local variable to a field".

Comment: Actually, one more question. I'm not sure how I can store the distance  variable into teh ArrayList because I've already made it store the neighbors. Is it possible to store another type of data with the nodeNeighbor? inside the ArrayList as well?

Comment: @Heuster: Yes, thanks a lot for pointing that out. I have fixed it.

Comment: @Liondancer: I have made some amendments to my code. I hope this helps.